# Error while compiling dsmodel.c in Dymola

Tags: compiler-errors, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openmodelica, dymola

So I cannot run any models on Dymola because I always get a compiling error on my laptop. I have installed different compilers (Visual Studio 2015,2019,2022 & MinGW etc..) but the problem seems not to go away. The Error message i get is the following: Dymola cannot compile a simple C-program, dsmodel.c in the current directory. Please check compiler installation.

Here is an image of the error message:

[Dymola Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LtqZ.png)

In the Simulations tab the following message is shown: WSL setup seems incorrect, as there are no messages from WSL.

I have also tried updating WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) to the latest version but unfortunately, that doesn't help the situation either.

Thank you for the help in advance!

I tried installing different compilers (MS Visual Studio 2015,2019,2022)
I tried running different versions of Dymola (2021, 2023x)
I tried updating WSL Windows Subsystem for Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for your answer Hans. I had to clean install windows last month because my hard drive was corrupted. I installed Dymola from scratch along with Visual Studio and now it seems to be working fine! I had tried your solution previously without success. But now the problems seems to be resolved anyways. Thanks!

Comment: If you find that my answer was good could you 'Accept' it? https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

One common explanation is that you haven't fully installed the compiler.

The manual states:

```
When installing any Visual Studio compiler, make sure that the option “C++/CLI 
support…” is also selected to be installed.
```

and links to https://www.3ds.com/products-services/catia/products/dymola/c-compiler/

which adds:

```
Note that Visual Studio performs parts of its installation the first time it is run. This must be performed in order to use Visual Studio with Dymola, a step that requires administrator privileges.
```

(and WSL has some additional steps as well).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me, it was due to an incompatible compiler version. In WSL, I had to upgrade to g++-11 to the compiler to work with dsmodel.c. For Visual Studio, I know that 2019 version works but I'm not sure about other versions.